# Doctrine2 innerJoin between two tables without association defined

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to join a table that has no association defined in my config file. Why? Because I don't want to pollute this entity (Section) because many other entity can be related to this one with a "Many to One" relation. So, I define the relation only on one side, so it doesn't pollute my Section entity.

What I'm trying to do is :

```
// Find all sections with this bundle linked
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('CompanyBackendSectionBundle:Section')->createQueryBuilder('s')
          ->select('s', 'st')
          ->innerJoin('s.translations', 'st')
          ->innerJoin('s.sectionBundles', 'sb')
          ->innerJoin('Company\Backend\FaqBundle\Entity\FaqQuestion', 'fq')
          ->where('st.locale = :locale')
          ->andWhere('sb.bundle = :bundleId')
          ->orderBy('st.name')
          ->setParameters(array(
              'locale' => $this->getLocale(),
              'bundleId' => $bundle->getId()
          ));
```

The problem is with "->innerJoin('Company\Backend\FaqBundle\Entity\FaqQuestion', 'fq')", I got :

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 179 near 'fq WHERE st.locale': Error: Identification Variable Company\Backend\FaqBundle\Entity\FaqQuestion used in join path expression but was not defined before.
```

Is there a way to do it other than using Doctrine Native Query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Doctrine Query Language needs you to define the relation in the direction you wanna use it...